# Custom shells started automatically from .emacs

Tags: shell, emacs, elisp

I would like to start a few shells, and set their directories from my .emacs. Opening them is easy:

```
;; run a few shells.
(shell "*shell5*")
(shell "*shell6*")
(shell "*shell7*")
```

But I would like to specify their directory, too.

Comment: Just an idea, and a bit hacky, but does the shell directory come from the currently open buffer's directory? If so, you could open a temp file in each directory, and start the shell after opening the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for me

```
(let ((default-directory "/path/to/whereever/"))
  (shell "*shell1*"))
```

Comment: Did not work for me, for example if i use /usr/src, the shell start on /usr only, the same happens with /home/guest, starting on /home

Comment: Try adding a trailing slash, i.e. "/path/to/wherever/".

Comment: Works, even with "\\" for backslash on windows. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
(shell "*shell5*")
(with-current-buffer "*shell5*"
(goto-char (point-max))
(insert "cd dir")) ;;for example
(comint-send-input nil t) ;; enter
```

For now I have this, its need some improvement I think. When I use in my emacs its causes an error, but does what you want. I will try to figure why.

Comment: That would be awesome. Have no time to playu with this now, maybe later tonight.

Comment: I think my accepted solution is probably better, but this idea is still interesting if I would like to do anything else in the shell!

Comment: Yeah, Ivan answer is a straightforward solution :)