# How can I reload the interactive shell and run some commands on emacs startup?

Tags: emacs

I relise that I have to add something like:

shell

: to my .emacs file. But then how can I get it to do shell commands like:

cd /mydirectory

: and other shell actions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a function which does what you want.  You can add it (customizing the actions), or just add the body:

```
(defun shell-and-stuff ()
  "run a shell, then do some extra stuff"
  (interactive)
  (let ((shell-buf (get-buffer-create "*shell*")))
    (shell shell-buf)
    (comint-send-string
     (get-buffer-process shell-buf)
     "cd some-directory
ls
touch frog
")))
(shell-and-stuff)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cd` part is easy, just `let` bind the variable `default-directory`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288594/custom-shells-started-automatically-from-emacs) for some possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Trey Jackson's idea looks good.  Also note that the manual `(info "(emacs) Interactive Shell")` says

> Emacs sends the new shell the contents of the file
>   `~/.emacs_SHELLNAME` as input, if it exists, where SHELLNAME is the
>   name of the file that the shell was loaded from.  For example, if you
>   use bash, the file sent to it is `~/.emacs_bash`.  If this file is not
>   found, Emacs tries to fallback on `~/.emacs.d/init_SHELLNAME.sh`.

So you could put your commands in that file.